# Cypress, test visiting a blocked link

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to visit a link that is blocked for the user. I simply use the `cy.visit()` function to do this. My problem now is that the site, as it should, isn't loading the page but waits a whole minute until it fails. [image]

And I'm searching for a solution that doesn't include decreasing the pageLoadTimeout.

So is there a way to check if the page isn't loading (blocked)? I tried to solve it with `.should()` and `{timouts}` but haven't found a solution to my problem.

Comment: Are you able to open the website outside of cypress ?

Comment: It's a direct link to a case. The user beforehand had permissions to visit that link. Then I have withdrawn the permissions for the case and now I want to test that the withdrawl of the permission worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using request instead of visit,

```js
cy.request('myurl', { failOnStatusCode: false})
  .then(response => {
    expect(response.status).not.to.eq(200)
  })
```